# How to average the values from multiple date ranges for Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My formula so far is:

```
=AVERAGEIFS('Main Run Log'!C:C,'Main Run Log'!A:A,">=11/13/22",'Main Run Log'!A:A,"<=1/14/23",'Main Run Log'!A:A,">=1/22/23",'Main Run Log'!A:A,"<=1/28/23")
```

The goal is to get the data (column C) that correspond to these two date ranges and average it.

What is the correct way of doing it? Thanks.

Comment: What is the version of your Excel?

Comment: I'm proposing a dumb answer.. pls share if it works.. "-_-  `(SUMIF(<range1formula>)+SUMIF(range2formula>))/(COUNTIF(<range1formula>)+COUNTIF(range2formula>))`

Comment: It's version 2016.

Comment: btw.. what is the error u got from using the current formula?

Comment: p._phidot_  post your answer officially, and I will choose you. You got the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

averageifs='Main Run Log C :C ,Main Run Log!A :A , >=11/13/22" Main Run Log A :A ,"<=1/14/23" Main Run Log A :A ,">=1/22/23" Main Run Log'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### `AVERAGE` With Date Conditions (`DATEVALUE`)

- If your date format is the default format (`mm/dd/yyyy`), the following should work. Also, it should work with dashes e.g. `11-13-2022` maybe even dots e.g. `11.13.2022`. You can easily test it by just replacing the separators in the first date with a different date separator. It worked even with mixed separators on my system. Your feedback is expected.

  ```
  =AVERAGE(('Main Run Log'!$C2:$C21)
  *(('Main Run Log'!$A$2:$A$21>=DATEVALUE("11/13/2022"))
  *('Main Run Log'!$A$2:$A$21<=DATEVALUE("01/14/2023"))
  +('Main Run Log'!$A$2:$A$21>=DATEVALUE("01/22/2023"))
  *('Main Run Log'!$A$2:$A$21<=DATEVALUE("01/28/2023"))))
  ```
- The following (`yyyy/mm/dd`) should work on any system possibly with other date separators. If someone knows that it doesn't, any feedback is welcome.

  ```
  =AVERAGE(('Main Run Log'!$C2:$C21)
  *(('Main Run Log'!$A$2:$A$21>=DATEVALUE("2022/11/13"))
  *('Main Run Log'!$A$2:$A$21<=DATEVALUE("2023/01/14"))
  +('Main Run Log'!$A$2:$A$21>=DATEVALUE("2023/01/22"))
  *('Main Run Log'!$A$2:$A$21<=DATEVALUE("2023/01/28"))))
  ```
- Note that `AVERAGEIFS` requires ranges, while `AVERAGE` also works with arrays.